# Replacing column values in MariaDB from other table

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have the following snippet pieced together from various other threads:

`UPDATE assets SET asset_tag=tmp_x.new FROM tmp_x WHERE asset_tag=tmp_x.old;`

`assets` is my table that contains the `asset_tag` column.

`tmp_x` includes two int columns, `old` and `new`.

I'm trying to update existing values in the `asset_tag` column via the `tmp_x` values, but in MariaDB the above command returns a syntax error. So far further research has yielded everything from `INNER JOIN` to merging the tables altogether, which seems a bit overkill.

An example from `assets`:

```
asset_tag   id
12345       1
12346       2
12347       3
```

And from `tmp_x`:

```
old     new
12345   88881
12346   88882
```

Note that not all values of `asset_tags` are in `tmp_x`, so I'm only changing a few.

Thank you in advance for any hints!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update assets as tgt
inner join tmp_x as src on tgt.asset_tag=src.old
set tgt.asset_tag=src.new
```

Comment: Thank you! This is nice and straightforward.

Comment: might run a little faster, too ;-)

Answer (score 0):

After several attempts that wiped my database a few times, turns out I was close, but not verbose enough. Here's the working command:

```
UPDATE assets 
SET asset_tag = (SELECT new FROM tmp_x WHERE old=asset_tag) 
WHERE asset_tag = (SELECT old FROM tmp_x WHERE old=asset_tag);
```

If there's a more elegant way of doing it, let me know!